# Standard install of gitlab produces 404

Tags: gitlab

I have installed GitLabv13 on ubuntu 20.04 using the standard procedure where *external_url* is set to a relative URL, i.e., http://www.example.com/gitlab.

I get a 404 when I navigate to the URL via the web browser.

I tried the basic troubleshooting found on GitLab's site, but that does fix the problem.
I am not running any firewall, and port 80 is not blocked.

What else should I try?

Comment: On a side note, Gitlab is using 100% of my CPU resource - 1CPU core and 2GB RAM - even before putting it to use..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to shutdown the existing Apache webserver running on the same machine, at which point, I no longer received a 404.  However, due to the minimum requirements - I am only running a single core CPU with 2GB RAM - I now receive a 502.

Answer (score 0):

First, the [CPU/Memory requirements](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html#cpu) for GitLab are more than 1 CPU/2GB.

Second, make sure *all* configuration files listed in "[Install GitLab under a relative URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/relative_url.html)" are modified.
The [troubleshooting page](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/common_installation_problems/#gitlab-is-unreachable-in-my-browser) suggests checking the format in `gitlab.rb`.

And [issue 244](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/244#note_19961082) suggests, for testing, to force the IP address in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: From the gitlab site:

>  Relative URL support in Omnibus GitLab is experimental and was
> introduced in version 8.5...

Comment: I am using Omnibus installer, thus the second recommendation is not applicable.  The first recommendation probably wouldn't cause this kind of thing.  I haven't found a solution yet.